# What airplane does this vintage instrument panel come from?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image: photo of instrument panel] 
Can anyone please tell me what this is from?

It looks like it's military. I have a few panels that came with this and gauges (not if it's a b-16)

Comment: Does looking up the N-number on the panel help at all?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject I searched, the FAA says it is not registered.

Comment: @Federico -- hrm.  I wonder if there's some historical registrations archive out there?

Comment: i think you might of got it i looked up cirrus glider it looks similar t\

Comment: What makes you say it's "vintage"?

Comment: Any info on how this panel made it all the way to Canada (possibly donated to an aviation museum in Brandon MB) and then passed along to me. Seems like it has had an interesting history.

Answer (score 11):

The shape makes it clear that this is from a single seater or tandem aircraft. This makes a glider very likely, which is supported by the "Vario" engraving over the column of small holes on the bottom right.

A little googling then brings me to [this page](http://www.rcawsey.co.uk/stdcir.htm) and the assumption that this panel is from a Schempp-Hirth [Standard Cirrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schempp-Hirth_Standard_Cirrus), Serial No. 176. The plane was badly damaged at [Minisink, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minisink,_New_York) on [October 23, 1976](https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/wiki.php?id=74652) in a botched landing and consequently written off. At that time it was registered as [N11JY](http://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/NNum_Results.aspx?NNumbertxt=N11JY).

[image: Schempp-Hirth Standard Cirrus]

<sub>Schempp-Hirth Standard Cirrus (picture [source](http://www.standardcirrus.org/Images/SA-20100728.jpg))</sub>

[image: Standard Cirrus instrument panel]

<sub>Standard Cirrus instrument panel (picture [source](http://www.standardcirrus.org/Images/330-GunnarBlake-1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: ok great thank you so much for your help

Comment: Misread "Minisink" as "Minsk" and was wondering what on earth a US-registered glider was doing in the Byelorussian SSR...

Answer (score 5):

It has the legend "Vario", short for [variometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variometer) stenciled on it and it looks very much like the [panel from a Cirrus sailplane](http://www.standardcirrus.org/Images/8-CS11-75L-01.jpg).

[image]
Source.  [Standard Cirrus](http://www.standardcirrus.org/)